# Creating a pipeline with the REST API causes error 400: INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am using a direct call to the Dataflow REST API (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/data-pipelines/rest/v1/projects.locations.pipelines/create) using the Python requests module to create a pipeline. I have retrieved the definition of an existing, working pipeline as a base, which I modified to create a new, different pipeline. I've double checked all the parameters but I still end up with `{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Request contains an invalid argument.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}}`
The API doesn't say what argument is invalid. What's going wrong? I'd like to use the proper client library for Python, but for Dataflow it's still in preview and does not support pipeline creation.

This is my code:

```py
body = {'name': 'projects/<project_id>/locations/europe-west1/pipelines/test_name',
 'displayName': 'test_name',
 'type': 'PIPELINE_TYPE_BATCH',
 'state': 'STATE_ACTIVE',
 'workload': {'dataflowFlexTemplateRequest': {'projectId': '<project_id>',
   'launchParameter': {'jobName': 'job_test2',
    'parameters': {'password': '<base64 encoded string>',
     'isTruncate': 'true',
     'useColumnAlias': 'true',
     'serviceAccount': 'censored@censored.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
     'experiments': 'use_runner_v2',
     'driverClassName': 'com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver',
     'connectionProperties': 'autosave=never',
     'workerMachineType': 'n2-highmem-4',
     'bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory': 'gs://censored-temp',
     'connectionURL': '<base64 encoded string>',
     'defaultWorkerLogLevel': 'DEBUG',
     'maxNumWorkers': '2',
     'query': 'select column1 from schema_name.table_name',
     'driverJars': 'gs://censored-assets/redshift-jdbc42-2.1.0.10.jar',
     'username': '<base64 encoded string>',
     'outputTable': '<project_id>:<dataset_name.<table_name>'},
    'containerSpecGcsPath': 'gs://dataflow-templates-europe-west1/latest/flex/Jdbc_to_BigQuery_Flex',
    'environment': {'workerZone': 'europe-west4-a',
     'kmsKeyName': 'projects/<project_id>/locations/global/keyrings/<keyring_id>/<key_id>'}},
   'location': 'europe-west1'}}}


headers = { 'Authorization': f'Bearer {creds.token}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
response = requests.post(url_create, json=body, headers=headers)
```

Result: `{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Request contains an invalid argument.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}}`

I've double checked that all the parameter values are correct, and I've also tried removing and changing some, to see if I can pinpoint which one is problematic, to no avail.

Comment: If it were me, I'd then start looking at the GCP log.  Maybe something is written there that gives more information?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the logs unfortunately.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Whatever permutation/combination I do, I always get `{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Request contains an invalid argument.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}}` without pointing out the actual issue. The same parameters work well with Scheduler & Dataflow REST API. 

In case of Data-Pipelines it's also unclear where to mention the `sdkContainerImage`. Couldn't find the same in the documentation.

Raised a bug for the same: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268426288